# How to integrate native ios third party library into react native app?

Tags: react-native

I need to extract tar file in react native app, and I found a library for doing that (react-native-archiver), but it supports only android not IOS.

I found this library on github [tarkit](https://github.com/daltoniam/tarkit), but how is it possible to add it to node modules like through npm install.

They mention how to untar file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* dataPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.tar.gz"];
NSString* toPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDir"];
[DCTar decompressFileAtPath:dataPath toPath:toPath error:nil];
```

And they mention that the recommended approach for installing tarkit is via the CocoaPods package manager (like most libraries):

```
pod 'tarkit', '~> 0.1.3'
```

I found this library that support react native but only zip files [react-native-zip-archive](https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive/blob/master/ios/RNZipArchive.m):

In RNZipArchive.m :

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(unzip:(NSString *)from
                  destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath
                  charset:(NSString *)charset
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    self.progress = 0.0;
    self.processedFilePath = @"";
    [self zipArchiveProgressEvent:0 total:1]; // force 0%

    NSError *error = nil;

    BOOL success = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:from toDestination:destinationPath overwrite:YES password:nil error:&error delegate:self];

    self.progress = 1.0;
    [self zipArchiveProgressEvent:1 total:1]; // force 100%

    if (success) {
        resolve(destinationPath);
    } else {
        reject(@"unzip_error", [error localizedDescription], error);
    }
}
```

In [tarkit](https://github.com/daltoniam/tarkit) I found this function untarFileAtPath:

```
+(BOOL)untarFileAtPath:(NSString*)tarFilePath toPath:(NSString*)path error:(NSError**)error
{
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([manager fileExistsAtPath:tarFilePath]) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:tarFilePath error:nil];
        unsigned long long size = [attributes[NSFileSize] longLongValue];
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:tarFilePath];
        return [self untarObject:fileHandle size:size toPath:path error:error];
    }
    if(error)
        *error = [self errorWithDetail:@"tar file not found" code:-2];
    return NO;
}
```

How I can export untarFileAtPath in [tarkit](https://github.com/daltoniam/tarkit) the same as unzip in [react-native-zip-archive](https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive/blob/master/ios/RNZipArchive.m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement a custom Native Module for iOS. Copy-paste working code and wrap it with RCT_EXPORT_METHOD and use resolvers to return a value.

And you need to name module somehow, so you'll get something like:

```
@implementation UnTar

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(UnTar);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD((untarFileAtPath:(NSDictionary *)fields
resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    NSString *tarFilePath = [RCTConvert NSString:fields[@"tarFilePath"]];
    NSString *destinationPath = [RCTConvert NSString:fields[@"destinationPath"]];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([manager fileExistsAtPath:tarFilePath]) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:tarFilePath error:nil];
        unsigned long long size = [attributes[NSFileSize] longLongValue];
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:tarFilePath];
        resolve([self untarObject:fileHandle size:size toPath:path error:error]);
    }
    if(error)
        *error = [self errorWithDetail:@"tar file not found" code:-2];
    reject();
}

@end
```

In React-Native:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
NativeModules.UnTar.untarFileAtPath({ tarFilePath, destinationPath })
```

I didn't run a code, so use it as a guide ) I'll try to 100% working code later, but I need to get all libraries in a place.

Comment: Ok thanks Jlexyc, I try to replicate what they did in unzip method of react-native -zip-archive library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution : first I install pod library by adding `pod 'tarkit', '~> 0.1.3'` in podfile, then run cd ios & pod install.

The code in extracttar.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

#import "tarkit/DCTar.h"
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface extracttar : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The code in extracttar.m :

```
#import "extracttar.h"
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>


#if __has_include(<React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>)
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#else
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#endif
@implementation extracttar
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getsomestring:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSString *string = @"hello from xcode react native";
  callback(@[string]);
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(untar:(NSString *)from
                  destinationPath:(NSString *)destinationPath
                  charset:(NSString *)charset
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success =[DCTar decompressFileAtPath:from toPath:destinationPath error:nil];
//BOOL success =[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:from toDestination:destinationPath overwrite:YES password:nil error:&error delegate:self];

    if (success) {
        resolve(destinationPath);
    } else {
        reject(@"unzip_error", [error localizedDescription], error);
    }
}
@end
```

The code in react native:

```
import {NativeModules, Alert} from "react-native";
var untarIOS = NativeModules.extracttar;
.....

untarIOS.untar(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/5.tar`,RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath,"")
```